# onPostExecute in Fragment not working (works in Activity)

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, findviewbyid

My problem: This code doesn't work in my activity I am trying to implement a gridView adapter that gets data from parse.com

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the gridview in gridview_main.xml
        gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new GridViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                phonearraylist);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

This is within my "DiscoverActivity" class that exteds SherlockFragment

public class DiscoverActivity extends SherlockFragment

```
// Declare Variables
GridView gridview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ImageAdapter adapter;
private List<ImageList> phonearraylist = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_discover,container,false);
//        GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
 //        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(view.getContext())); // uses the view to get the context instead of getActivity().
    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
    return view;
}

private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

//            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Loading...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // Create the array
    phonearraylist = new ArrayList<ImageList>();
    try {
        // Locate the class table named "SamsungPhones" in Parse.com
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "testData2");
        // Locate the column named "position" in Parse.com and order list
        // by ascending
        query.orderByAscending("Price");
        ob = query.find();
        for (ParseObject country : ob) {
            ParseFile image = (ParseFile) country.get("Photo");
            ImageList map = new ImageList();
            map.setPhone(image.getUrl());
            phonearraylist.add(map);
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

//Here is what I have tried so far...
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // Locate the gridview in gridview_main.xml
    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
    //adapter = new ImageAdapter(DiscoverActivity.this,
      //      phonearraylist);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(view.getContext())); // uses the view to get the context instead of getActivity().
    // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
    // Close the progressdialog
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
}
}
```

I am undable to findViewById in my onPostExecute

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

Comment: the fact that you created the view does not mean it is in the hierarchy and can be found yet. you need to start your asynctask at a later moment.

Comment: why did you comment out the line that instantiated the `GridView` inside the `onCreate()` method - this seems like the appropriate place to get a pointer to the view?

Comment: It was working that way because I was testing out my layout before I try to get data from an external source. I am following this tutorial which is where I am getting this information from [link](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-gridview-tutorial/)

Comment: in the example the parent class is `Activity` which has a method `findViewById()` your parent class `SherlockFragment` does not. Therefore, you need to get a reference to the `gridView` using the layout that you inflate in `onCreate` (as you were doing), I say this assuming that the `gridview` is in the layout

Comment: Would you mind also explaining how my onPostExecute would work that way? The help is very appreciated!

Comment: Because your `asyncTask` is an inner class it has access to the instance variables of the outer class (your fragment class) you can create a pointer to the `gridview` in `oncreate` and use it in `onpostexecute`

Comment: Why don't you use .findInBackground() to call an async query? You can the call .setAdapter in the done() callback. 
You could also use a GridView from Parse api, there is a section in the documentation that explain how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

have you wrote this statement in the onCreate method? (of the activity)

```
setContentView(R.layout.some_activity);
```

then you can use all id's defined there.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have referenced the parent class is Activity which has a method `findViewById()` your parent class `SherlockFragment` does not. Therefore, you need to get a reference to the `gridView` using the layout that you inflate in `onCreate()` (as you were doing), I say this assuming that the `GridView` is in the layout.

Because your `AsyncTask` is an inner class it has access to the instance variables of the outer class (your fragment class) you can create a pointer to the `GridView` in `onCreate()` and use it in `onPostExecute()`